# Unable to resize secondary hard disk in GParted - too many primary partitions

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have an SSD that has Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 installed - both boot fine and Windows 10 was installed after Ubuntu - this is sdb - screenshot below

[image]

I have a secondary 3TB HDD that i was using with Ubuntu asnd is formatted as ext4 - screenshot below
[image]

When I try to resize this sda partition on Ubuntu, using gparted from a LiveUSB, screenshot:
[image]

I get the error "Too many primary partitions" when I try to create the second NTFS partition in the new unallocated space, even though it would be only the second primary partition on this HDD.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please advise

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Have you tried performing the operations one at a time? First shrink the partition, complete the action, then come back and add the new partition. Or did the shrinking successfully complete?

Comment: Better to show partitions with `sudo parted -l` or `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdb` rather than screen shot. Gdisk may show issue better also. Also shows more info on drive. Is drive gpt partitioned? It must be gpt partitioned.